# Theano assertion error

Tags: python, theano, blas, keras, intel-mkl

When I run Theano and want to train a 2D convolutional network I get the following error:

```
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Optimization failure due to: local_abstractconv_check
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): node: AbstractConv2d{border_mode='half', subsample=(1, 1), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, None, None, None), kshp=(32, 3, 3, 3), filter_dilation=(1, 1)}(convolution2d_input_1, convolution2d_1_W)
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): TRACEBACK:
ERROR (theano.gof.opt): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nicol\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\opt.py", line 1820, in process_node
    replacements = lopt.transform(node)
  File "C:\Users\nicol\Anaconda3\envs\py34\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\nnet\opt.py", line 409, in local_abstractconv_check
    node.op.__class__.__name__)
AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU, is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?
```

I have Anaconda (which includes MKL) installed with python 3.4 with the latest version of Theano. I also installed mingw and libpython. I checked the presence of BLAS by running the check_blas.py script provided by Theanom which said that Theano is connected to BLAS through numpy.

I do not now what is wrong and still (obiously) want the optimizers to work. I have seen several posts online with this problem but none of them got a real solution other than installing something else or not using optimizers. Does anyone know how to prevent this error?

Comment: This may be better suited for the Theano bug tracker I think.